# how to decrypt EncryptedSharedPreferences on a rooted device?

Tags: android, encryption, sharedpreferences, keystore, android-keystore

I have exported EncryptedSharedPreferences from the app, here is the content:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8' standalone='yes' ?>
<map>
    <string name="AUo6ivXovxpRsbNJ50Ppyd3m+VVn0bmdtXF5z/gwsc4ZP0cNZ1ZD6h4nUTNpNSBR">AXRNv7fSi+PoeIX7NjGw5eNdAbHJddezniXzOAJRyGzA792XKEw=</string>
    <string name="AUo6ivXkEe01bO3bVB2Ok/lpaW6mq/ixdJIA+tHIn5xKvQ==">AXRNv7cniXOk31gOs36TYZaMaLlmkr1oTmFdSpyi6INFSOayLUvhzAisMLcSqLNdyR4dIgzelKXwDS7gXB5MMj5MbMQ+ILUQ8WYup1A=</string>
    <string name="__androidx_security_crypto_encrypted_prefs_value_keyset__">1288018ce5d5734c3589a39124f9689f9ce9be73a5413e87dfb9e82332f189bbbc601db36a124e27b8a349caf7356c9e7cb82efd04fed780ba97d4a58ac8dfa1f223f0d37bc7e2f936b45e732af2e5c5d81b55c83320fff25c8b1452b4f4caa876b8c9d9f4965cf2ae212619b54a43b6e32878959abc84d8c8d7e12bbcb077f04a38af580b2cfcf1d9bbf71a4408b7ffb6a207123c0a30747970652e676f6f676c65617069732e636f6d2f676f6f676c652e63727970746f2e74696e6b2e41657347636d4b6579100118b7ffb6a2072001</string>
    <string name="__androidx_security_crypto_encrypted_prefs_key_keyset__">12a9010170896819ea02fc22af266664dd659f2448e8ba2cf4d4580c3d14921ff9dc7ae73ce8b72414af21f411f786eb0fabde07f09899cdebd76e0c68804d584c0f7b625cd304c0a3119acdbca95fa792df7c1a521d34f07218f83c71cc15d8e6e33128d93fc4020a1cfd17c1ed21e03e56e42201424286f0b4aaef85cacafdcafaa93409e4f90e0f31f54d441597aa2a2a285cfce75944542f645c3f3c2053bc21f1fbc6cbb2df2e1d9daa1a4408f595ead104123c0a30747970652e676f6f676c65617069732e636f6d2f676f6f676c652e63727970746f2e74696e6b2e4165735369764b6579100118f595ead1042001</string>
</map>
```

I also extracted master key from android keystore from data/misc/keystore/user_0, there were 2 files:

.10044_chr_USRSKEY__androidx_security_master_key_

10044_USRSKEY__androidx_security_master_key_

[click here to download master key files](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1itWj9_U3vTh6ePJy4w139iJ__WvKnZBD/view?usp=sharing)

I did a few tests and figured out that you can just delete .10044_chr_USRSKEY__androidx_security_master_key_ and program keep working as it supposed to, but if you delete 10044_USRSKEY__androidx_security_master_key_ it can not decrypt EncryptedSharedPreferences anymore

So after my research I figured out that `__androidx_security_crypto_encrypted_prefs_value_keyset__` and `__androidx_security_crypto_encrypted_prefs_key_keyset__` are encrypted with a master key which is stored in android keystore, and you firstly need to decrypt the keyset, and only after that decrypt the information stored in EncryptedSharedPreferences

Comment: The Android KeyStore is usually hardware backed, so files you find will not be sufficient to decode. But weakness of Android KeyStore on rooted device is that you can just kindly ask the KeyStore to decrypt the keys/data you need. You simply need to inject the code to do so into the app process that has created the file. https://labs.withsecure.com/publications/how-secure-is-your-android-keystore-authentication  (I think you can even take the origin (process) of the request, but I am not sure how to do so).